# Perl and wireshark export file dialog

Tags: perl, wireshark

I am interested in opening a capture file in wireshark and then exporting the data in "C arrays" format [Wireshark provides that option in its GUI. One can do it by following "File->Export->as C arrays file" from the main menu.My question is how can I do this in perl? Can someone help me with a script for this?

---

I Would like to parse each and every packet of the wireshark capture. So I thought, I will first convert each packet to an array and then parse it. Do you have any suggestions on this? My capture consists of all IEEE 802.11 frames.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with Perl? Read in the data to a Perl array from the C arrays stored in the file?

If this is what you want to do, then I suggest taking a look at `Net::Sharktools` package on CPAN - which will read a `pcap` file into a Perl hash.

Comment: Is there any sample code for using Net::Sharktools? I dont quite get what perlshark_read is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all the parsing yourself, i.e. look at the raw packet data, I would suggest writing your own program using libpcap to read pcap-format capture files (on UN*X, libpcap 1.1.0 and later can also read pcap-ng-format capture files, which is what Wireshark 1.8.0 and later write by default).  No need to write stuff out as C arrays.